# Form Region Custom Action

Tags: vb.net, forms, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I imported one form region with a commandbutton to my project.

I created a customaction to my formdesigner.vb like this

```
Private Shared Sub InitializeManifest(ByVal manifest As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionManifest, ByVal factory As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.Factory)
            Dim FormRegionCustomActionImpl1 As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionCustomAction = factory.CreateFormRegionCustomAction
            FormRegionCustomActionImpl1.Body = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionCustomActionBody.Prefix
            FormRegionCustomActionImpl1.Method = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionCustomActionMethod.Send
            FormRegionCustomActionImpl1.Name = "Complete"
            FormRegionCustomActionImpl1.ShowOnRibbon = False
            FormRegionCustomActionImpl1.SubjectPrefix = "Completed: "
            FormRegionCustomActionImpl1.Title = "Complete"
            manifest.CustomActions.Add(FormRegionCustomActionImpl1)
            manifest.FormRegionName = "CallCenterRd"
            manifest.FormRegionType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionType.Replacement
            manifest.ShowInspectorCompose = False
            manifest.Title = "Test"

        End Sub
```

How can I "run" this action when I click my forms region commandbutton?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom action can be executed by name, by obtaining it from the MailItem.Actions collection and calling Action.Execute:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff868574.aspx

Comment: Hi again.Almost got it...now when i use the click event                    Private Sub commandButton1_Click() Handles commandButton1.Click
        Dim myItem As Object
        myItem = Me.OutlookItem.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

        myItem.actions("Complete").Execute()
    End Sub                                                                                                i am receiving System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Your code is failing on Me.OutlookItem. Me is not a valid object, nor is OutlookItem. Try myItem = Application.CreateItem